# Best way to change CSS Background Image on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, caching

I have a Full-Screen Background image that I need to swap out for other images when hovering over a div. I'm doing this with jQuery - the problem is there's a fairly significant load time.

Is there a way to structure this so that the image appears near-instantaneously on the first hover? Code I have below:

```js
$("#hover-bg-2").mouseover(function() {
  $("#container").css("background", "url(/assets/image-2.jpg)");
  $("#container").css("-webkit-background-size", "cover");
  $("#container").css("-moz-background-size", "cover");
  $("#container").css("-o-background-size", "cover");
  $("#container").css("background-size", "cover");
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* ORIGINAL IMAGE BEFORE CHANGE */
  background: url(/assets/image-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="bg-hover">
    <div id="hover-bg-2" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <p>BG 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What size are images?

Comment: One thing I would note, is there is no need to keep setting the background properties in the JavaScript, since only the URL is changing. I would also modify the CSS to use `background-image` instead of `background`, and instead specify the other background properties individually, since again, you're only swapping out the URL, so no need to repeat that info e.g. `background-position`, `background-repeat` etc.

Comment: the images are 1200 x 675 @lomboboo

Comment: @nickrigby thanks for pointing that out - the thing is I tried just swapping out the URL and the positioning doesn't stay the same unless I explicitly rewrite the same rules

Comment: @SamYoungNY It should, but you will need to make sure you specify just to change the `background-image` in the JavaScript too e.g. `$("#container").css("background-image", "url(/assets/image-2.jpg)");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS3 (most browsers should support this by now). It also will have the advantage of working even if javascript wont.

You can do this with this:

```
.classToChange{
    background: "oldbackground.jpg"
}

.classToHoverOver:hover .classToChange{
      background: "newbackground.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Link Prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) in your `<head>` is the easiest way to reduce the loading time, no matter what swapping method you use method.

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="/images/big.jpeg">
```

I'm not sure why Safari doesn't support this, but [the other browsers do](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `class` of your container using mouse events, load css initially, just change `class` of your container using `Jquery`

**For example** :

```js
$("#hover-bg-2").hover(function() {
  $('#container')
    .removeClass("class_default")
    .addClass("other");
}, function() {
  $('#container')
    .removeClass("other")
    .addClass("class_default");;
});
```

```css
.class_default {
  /* your style goes here */
  background: red;
}
.other{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="class_default">

  <div class="bg-hover">
    <div id="hover-bg-2" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <p>BG 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>
```